# AWS ECS Blue/Green deployment loses my code

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs, blue-green-deployment

I have a `python3` project which runs in a `docker` `container` environtment.

My Python project uses `AWS Acces keys` and `secret` but using a credentials file stored in the computer which is added to the container using `ADD`.

I deployed my project to `EC2`. The server has one task running which works fine. I am able to go through port `8080` to the `webserver` (`Airflow`).

When I do a new commit and push to a `master branch` in github, the hook download the content and deploy it without build stage.

The new code is in the `EC2` server, I check it using `ssh` but the container that runs in the task get "stuck" and the `bind volumes` dissapear and they are not working until I restart a new task. The volumes are applied again from 0, and those reference to the new code. This action is fully manual.

Then, to fix it I listen about `AWS ECS Blue/Green` deployment, so I implemented it. In this case the `Codepipeline` add a `build` stage, but here starts the problem. If in the build I try to push a `docker image` to the `ECR`, which my task definition makes reference it fails. It fails because in the server, and in the repo (which I commit push my new code) there is no credentials file.

I tryed doing the latest `docker image` from my `localhost`, and avoiding build stage in `codepipeline`, and it works fine, but then when I go to the `8080` port in both working ip's I am able to get in the webserver, but the code is not there. If i click anywhere it says code not found.

So, in a general review I would like to understand what i am doing wrong, and how to fix in a general guidelines, and in the other hand ask why my `EC2` instance in the `AWS ECS Blue/Green` cluster has 3 ip's.

[image]

The first one is the one that I use to reach server through port 22. And if there I run `docker ps` I see one or two containers running depending if I am in the middle of a new deployment. If here I search my new code its not here...

The other two ip's are changing after every `deployment` (I guess its blue and green) and both work fine until `Codepipeline` destroys the green one (5 minutes wait time), but the code is not there. I know it because when I click in any of the links in the webserver it fails saying the `Airflow Dag` hasn't been found.

So my problem is that I have a fully working `AWS ECS Blue/Green deployment` but without my code. Then my webserver doesn't have anything to run.

Comment: You have 3 IPs, because two are for your tasks - guess you are using `awsvpc` networking mode. So if you do b/g you will need two more IPs. Can you container instance handle 5 ENI in total?

Comment: @Marcin What do you mean if it can handle 5 ENI? Wha'ts the point of handle 5?

Comment: Elastic network interface. If you use `awsvpc`, which seems to be the case, each task will need to have its own ENI attached to an instance.

Comment: @Marcin, yes and its working. But never tried with 5 ENI. Why did you ask for just 5? The point of the question is that my code is not propagated to the task :S

Comment: You ask why you have 3 IPs and why green environment terminates after a timeout? Have I misunderstood your issue?

Comment: @Marcin well as I writte in the last paragraph: "So my problem is that I have a fully working AWS ECS Blue/Green deployment but without my code. Then my webserver doesn't have anything to run."

I understand why had 3 ip's, and just one is the "real" ip. Green environtment ends after 5 minutes because is my terminate time setup when deploying. The issue is that my last merged code in my branch in github is not in the server.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand how something can be "fully working", yet not giving you your desired outcome. But its ok. Hopefully someone else will be able to provide better help.